# Can Delphi XE6 compile for Windows Phone?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

When I create FireMonkey application, I can't compile it for Windows Phone... why is that? I read that it should support it? How do I compile Windows Phone application?

Comment: Can you provide a backup on your claim? I never heard about XE6 being able to compile for WinPhone ..

Comment: Probably misunderstood sentence "Delphi XE6 Firemonkey On Android, Windows, OSX, And IOS", thought that Firemonkey is Mobile only. Last version of Delphi I used was 7. So alot have changed :-)

Comment: Firemonkey is multi-platform alternative to VCL. It works on Windows too, so that all listed platforms can reuse 98% same code.

Comment: @Krom Windows x86 desktop only. So not WinPhone or WinRT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi does not support Windows Phone. The only mobile platforms supported are iOS and Android on ARM.

Comment: I think you'd be much better off with something like Xamarin

Comment: I don't like C :-) Anyway are there alot phones that are not ARM with Android?

Comment: Xamarin is not C. Personally, I don't like not being able to target important platforms. For example during all those fallow years before the x64 delphi compiler arrived. Most Android devices are on ARM but there are some devices on other archs.

Comment: I agree, but I'm big fan of Delphi, and just starting with mobile apps, so Android support is enough for now. Just wondered about Windows Phones, but they are not popular at all... PS. I like Delphi, because I was starting with Delphi 5 (not counting Pascal or Basic).

Comment: I've just had to do some support for a delphi program written 10 years ago and honestly, having looked at all the advancements Delphi has made, it's still in the stoneage. What a pity: I used to love the language